# Classic asp build menu from DB with submenu's

Tags: database, asp-classic, menu, submenu

HI Im totally lost i have a menu that creates itself by using the users security level

However i do not know how to show submenus i have a parentid on my table but do not know enough to implement into the code can somebody help i have input my template code

```
Dim CurrentSecLev                   'security level of the requested menu item
Dim MenuLink                        'filename or url of the menu item
Dim MenuText                        'display text of the menu item

'build sql query string, open database, and execute the query
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM dbo.tblMenus where mnuParentID = 0 ORDER BY mnuOrder"
objConn.Open
set objResults=objConn.Execute(strsql)

'loop through the records and build the menu
do while not objResults.eof
CurrentSecLev=objResults("mnuSecLev")
MenuLink=objResults("mnuLink")
MenuText=objResults("mnuText")

'check to ensure that the users security level meets or exceeds the required
'security level of the current menu item.  This ensures that only authorized
'users see certain menu items, such as 'Site Admin'.
if MySecLev => CurrentSecLev then
    response.write "<li><a href='" & MenuLink & "'>" & MenuText & "</a></li>" & vbcrlf
        end if
'rock on
objResults.Movenext
Loop

'close and destroy the recordset, close the database.
objResults.Close
set objResults=Nothing
objConn.Close

'check to see if the user is logged in.  if they are, display the logout
'option.  if they are not logged in, display the login option.
If LoggedIn="Yes" Then 
response.write "<li><a href='logout.asp'>Logout</a></li>" & vbcrlf
Else
response.write "<li><a href='login.asp'>Login</a></li>" & vbcrlf
End if
%></ul><Form Action="searchresults.asp" method=post id=form3 name=form3><p><input   name="searchquery" id="searchquery" size="10"/><input name="Submit" id="Submit" type="submit" value="Search!" /></p></form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<%
Dim rsArray 
Dim rs
objConn.Open
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblKBMain where title <> '' or [content] <> ''"
Set rs = objconn.execute(strSQL) 
if not rs.eof then 
rsArray = rs.GetRows() 
nr = UBound(rsArray, 2) + 1 
Response.write "<p>" & nr & " articles</p>" 
end if 
rs.close
set rs = nothing 
objConn.Close
%>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, took a quick look at your code. But I'm only going to give you a basic guide to sub-menus.

If you're using sub-menus, then you need to setup a parentID in the table, which you already have. The parentID will be equal to the menuID of its "parent". I.e. If "File" has a menuID of 1, then "Open" will have a parentID of 1. All top level menus will have a parentID of 0.

Then you do a query of the menu table where parentID=0.

```
For each menu item, 
  you first display it,
  Then you do another query on the same table where parentID={the menuID of the item you just displayed},
  Then for each one of those, 
    you again display it.
    If you have 3 levels of menus, do yet another query for those.  
      ...  
    end loop of level 3  
  end loop of level 2  
end loop of level 1
```

The display of the menu items differs by the method you use. Most use

```
<ul><li>
```

Do a google search for CSS menus.

Comment: Hi Thanks for that but i am a real novice so i kind of understand the above but wouldnt knwo where to start is there any chance of showing me using the code above? please